# imagerotate fails for small image

Tags: php, image-rotation, php-gd

I have a 1x2px image, when I use imagerotate I get this error

```
Warning: imagerotate(): gd warning:
one parameter to a memory allocation multiplication is negative or zero,
failing operation gracefully in file#line
```

Sample code
header('Content-type: image/png');

```
$angle = 320;

$image = imagecreatefrompng('small.png');
$bg_color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
$temp_image = imagerotate($image, -$angle, $bg_color);
imagesavealpha($image, 1);

imagepng($image);
```

Is there a workaround for this issue?

PHP 5.5.12
WAMP

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried changing `$angle` from 320 to 40? What I mean is, instead of `$temp_image = imagerotate($image, -$angle, $bg_color);`, use `$temp_image = imagerotate($image, 360-$angle, $bg_color);`

Comment: Do you think you could provide `small.png`?

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: Here's the link to the image http://postimg.org/image/i5c1oovk1/63a4ab94/

Comment: For small angles below 75°, `image_rotate` succeeds as the image isn't changed

Comment: GD does some '[fuzzing](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1c295d4a9ac78fcc2f77d6695987598bb7abcb83/ext/gd/libgd/gd_interpolation.c#L1714)' of the width/height that obviously results in a number < 1. A dirty solution would be to increase the size, rotate, decrease the size. Out of curiosity, how would the result be useful? I can't even get a good result in a regular graphics application.